# python comparing parentheses from user input and making sure they have a pair

Tags: python

I'm writing a program to take a user input of parentheses i.e. {} [] () and checking to see if they have a pair (opening and closing). I'm running into an error when running my code where i always get the return false. I've tried different ways of checking against a pre set "list" but it doesn't seem to work. I have to use the class from above too. any help is appreciated.

some example inputs are:

```
    >>>parenthesesMatch('{[]}')
    True
    >>>parenthesesMatch('({})')
    True
    >>>parenthesesMatch('{[)]}')
    False
```

My code:

```
    #George flamburis


class Stack():
def __init__(self,que=[]):
    self.lst = que
def __repr__(self):
    return "Stack({})".format(self.lst)
def push(self, add):
    self.lst.append(add)
def pop(self):
    return self.lst.pop()
def isEmpty(self):
    return self.lst==[]
def first(self, loc=0):            #naming of this method can't be []
    return self.lst[loc]
def len(self):
    return len(self.lst)

def parenthesesMatch(match):
     s = Stack()
     end = []
     for char in match:
         if char in "[ { (":
             s.push(char)
         else:
             end.append(char)

     if s.len()==len(end):
             for num in range(len(end)):
                     if s.first(num) and end[num] not in '[]' or '{}' or'()':
                             return False
             return True
     elif s.len()!=len(end):
             return False
```

Comment: what is your question?

 also your code is not working in Python 2.7, the parenthesesMatch(match) is missing a self?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's much easier to simply attempt to pop a closing character off the stack when you see one, and fail if that isn't possible.

```
pairs = dict(tuple(pair) for pair in ["()", "[]", "{}"])
# pairs["("] == ")"
# pairs["["] == "]"
# etc
def parenthesesMatch(match):
    s = Stack()
    for char in match:
        # Not "] } )"
        if char in pairs.values() and pairs[s.pop()] != char:
            return False
        elif char in pairs:
            s.push(char)
    return s.isEmpty()
```

Comment: This function implementation fails on simple inputs such as `[{}]` and `{}()`

Comment: Thanks; I forget we were looking for a matching pair, not a literal character match.

Comment: I think, this is simplest solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, when you explain it along with you code it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
def match(par):
    combs = {'{': '}', '(': ')', '[': ']'}
    stack = []
    for char in par:
        if char in '[{(':
            stack.append(char)
        elif char == combs[stack[len(stack) - 1]]:
            stack.pop()
        else:
            return False
    return len(stack) == 0
```

Comment: What for par='[[['?

Answer (score 0):

Comments outline my thought.

```
def isParenthesesMatch(s):
    # to be balanced should be divisable by 2
    if len(s)%2 != 0:
        return False
    open_paren = ['(','[','{']
    open_paren_stack = list()
    match_close_paren = {')' : '(',']': '[', '}' : '{'}
    for item in s:
        #Don't care about open
        if item in open_paren:
            open_paren_stack.append(item)
        #if closed we should be able to pop
        elif len(open_paren_stack) == 0:
            return False
        #if we can pop it should match up
        elif open_paren_stack.pop() != match_close_paren[item]:
            return False
    #in case we push a bunch of open and then end with balanced pair    
    return len(open_paren_stack) == 0
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def parenthesesMatch(match):
    counter = {'{': 0, '[': 0, '(': 0, '}': 0, ']': 0, ')': 0}
    parantheses = '{}[]()'
    for character in match:
        if character not in parantheses:
            continue

        counter[character] += 1
    return (counter['{'] == counter['}']) and (counter['['] == counter[']']) and (counter['('] == counter[')'])
```

Comment: This simply returns true if each type has the same amount within the string. Therefore causing inputs such as `[{]}` to evaluate as true because there is a match for the `[` and `]`, and `{` and `}` even though they are clearly out of order.